# HID events on a inputText box

Tags: java, jsf, hid

I have designed a standalone application using swings which can read data from HID device using HID events.  I am asked to implement same on a website.  How can I handle HID events on a `h:inputText` box in JSF.  Is this possible?  If not, what are the possible alternatives?

Comment: You mean, you want to capture mouse and key events like `keyup`, `mousedown`, etc which all occur inside the `<input type="text">` element as generated by a `<h:inputText>`?

Comment: No, I want to capture HID events

Comment: How exactly is `<h:inputText>` related to the question then?

Comment: I want `h:inputText` to read data from HID device using HID events instead of key events or mouse events.  If thats not possible, I would like to know the alternatives.

Comment: So, the concrete functional requirement is to set a HID event value as a `h:inputText` value by JavaScript? By the way, a HID device is a generic term for an user input device such as keyboard and mouse. If you don't mean it to be a keyboard or mouse, you'd need to be more specific.

Comment: HID device in context is a Secure Card Reader http://www.magtek.com/V2/products/secure-card-reader-authenticators/Dynamag.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *HID device in context is a Secure Card Reader*

Well, you'd need to create a signed [Java Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) or [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) (JNLP) Application (which can use the same code as you used in the Swing application). This allows you to execute Java (Swing) code in the client side. Finally you can embed this applet or JNLP application in your JSF page the usual way. You can interact between the applet or JNLP application and the JSF-generated HTML page using the JavaScript API.

There is in JavaScript no standard way to capture events from an arbitrary device other than keyboard and mouse. As JSF is basically just a HTML/CSS/JS code generator, it can't do any much for you here.